# How to initialize injected form-backing model bean?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So I have model entity `Place` that has to have initialized some relations.
Now I am using autocreated model form-backing bean in controller as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/add")
public String addPlacePage(final Place place, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("services", serviceRepository.findAll())
            .addAttribute("categories", categoryRepository.findAll())
            .addAttribute("cities", cityRepository.findAll());
    return "admin/place/addPlace";
}
```

`Place place` is created my Spring (Spring-MVC probably). Is there a way to provide a factory method for backing bean? I would like to not to do this in controller.

I have tried to put factory code in my configuration like this:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public Place place() {
    log.info("Creating place in FACTORY");
    Place place = EntityFactory.emptyPlace();
    return place;
}
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So I have ask the same question in #spring channel on freenode, and this is something that came up thanks to user **<@_ollie>**. In order  to do what I want, `@ModelAttribute` method should be defined in controller like this:

```
@ModelAttribute
private Place emptyPlace(){
    log.info("Creating place in FACTORY");
    Place place = EntityFactory.emptyPlace();
    return place;
}
```

and related docs are here
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods